# Getting a handle on GIS math, where do I start?

Tags: math, gis, topology, wgs84, utm

I am in charge of a program that is used to create a set of nodes and paths for consumption by an autonomous ground vehicle.  The program keeps track of the locations of all items in its map by indicating the item's position as being x meters north and y meters east of an origin point of 0,0.  In the real world, the vehicle knows the location of the origin's lat and long, as it is determined by a dgps system and is accurate down to a couple centimeters.  My program is ignorant of any lat long coordinates.

It is one of my goals to modify the program to keep track of lat long coords of items in addition to an origin point and items' x,y position in relation to that origin.  At first blush, it seems that I am going to modify the program to allow the lat long coords of the origin to be passed in, and after that I desire that the program will automatically calculate the lat long of every item currently in a map.  From what I've researched so far, I believe that I will need to figure out the math behind converting to lat long coords from a UTM like projection where I specify the origin points and meridians etc as opposed to whatever is defined already for UTM.

I've come to ask of you GIS programmers, am I on the right track?  It seems to me like there is so much to wrap ones head around, and I'm not sure if the answer isn't something as simple as, "oh yea theres a conversion from meters to lat long, here"

Currently, due to the nature of DGPS, the system really doesn't need to care about locations more than oh, what... 40 km? radius away from the origin.  Given this, and the fact that I need to make sure that the error on my coordinates is not greater than .5 meters, do I need anything more complex than a simple lat/long to meters conversion constant?

I'm knee deep in materials here.  I could use some pointers about what concepts to research.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a start point in lat/long and a distance and bearing, finding the end point is a geodesic calculation.  There's a great summary of geodesic calculations and errors on the [proj.4 website](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GeodesicCalculations).  They come to the conclusion that using a spherical model can get results for distance between points with at most 0.51% error.  That, combined with a formula to translate between [WGS-84 and ECEF](http://www.microem.ru/pages/u_blox/tech/dataconvert/GPS.G1-X-00006.pdf) (see the "LLA to ECEF" and "ECEF to LLA" sections, seems like it gets you what you need.

If you want to really get the errors nailed down by inverse projecting your flat map to WGS-84, [proj.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) is a projection software package.  It has source code, and comes with three command line utilities - `proj`, which converts to/from cartographic projection and cartesian data; `cs2cs`, which converts between different cartographic projections; and `geod`, which calculates geodesic relationships.

The USGS publishes a [very comprehensive treatment of map projections](http://pubs.er.usgs.gov/djvu/PP/PP_1395.pdf).

Comment: Links are broken.

Comment: ie, 404 here https://proj.org/wiki/GeodesicCalculations

Answer (score 2):

I'd do a full-up calculation if you can.  That way you'll always be as accurate as you can be.

If you happen to be using C++ the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) is a very good library.

Comment: It will be accurate, also probably easier to implement. Just hook in a good library.

Answer (score 0):

For a range of 40km, you may find that approximating the world to a 2D flat surface may work, although a UTM transform would be the ideal way to go - in any case, I'd advocate using the actual WGS84 co-ordinates & ellipsoid for calculations such as great circle distance, or calculating bearings.

If you get bored, you could go down a similar line to something I've been working on, that can be used as a base class for differing datums such as OSGB36 or WGS84...

Comment: Now that you mention it, by UTM transform, do you mean locating my origin at a lat long, then finding what UTM zone my origin is in, (and converting all of my items x,y to a real life UTM xy)?  Or do you mean making my own fake utm zone whose origin is my origin and going from there?

Comment: I was thinking convert to UTM's x,y - you can adjust for a false origin for your uses, if required.